# store image in a folder form a list in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to store a image in to a folder which I have selected from a list in silverlight

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: you want to download the image from server to the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight you have only limited access to the file system for security reason. 
So everything what you want to save would end up in IsolatedStorage...

Check out this Quickstart Video and let me know if it helps

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight, You have limited access to the client file system. If you are running Out Of Browser application with elevated permission, you can access User folders (My documents in windows).

But you can try some workarounds like using JavaScript u can try to download file. For reference [Download a picture OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227157/html-javascript-download-a-picture-onclick)