# Code for left mouse click download of image files?

Tags: download, hyperlink, image

I have a download section in my website where I want to have a download link for my gallery. A left mouse click should bring up the browser's download screen **rather than** loading up the image. How is this possible? Is it possible to do in HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: Have a look here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227157/download-a-picture-onclick

Comment: I did. That question had a PHP solution - is it possible to do this without php code? In HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good amount of google-ing I would now say NO.